# How to use different fonts based on the language of the currently active keyboard layout?

Tags: microsoft-windows, fonts

I want to make Emacs aware of the *language* I input -- in my case, Arabic, English, German -- so that I can use different fonts for each of them.  So, for example, I'd like Emacs to use the following fonts when I'm entering text in the following languages:

```
Arabic  - DejaVu Sans Mono 14  
English - Consolas 11  
German  - Consolas 12
```

So:

- How can I set this up in my init file?
- Where do I find the exact names of languages in Emacs to be recognized by the code?

(Side note: I'm new to Emacs and am just starting to learn `elisp`.)

*Clarifying to follow-up on comments:*

- I'm using Windows.  Ideally, I'd like Emacs to understand what language I'm using based on the Language Bar.

**Update:**
A better approach to this problem is posted [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/how-to-assign-a-certain-font-for-each-text-input-method-in-emacs-24/5525#5525).

Comment: Do you mean your operating system's current [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method)? The currently set keyboard layout? Or are you asking for something that would somehow recognize what language you're inputting, no matter what the operating system level options are (like, it should recognize if you're typing german, even if your keyboard layout is english)?

Comment: yes to the latter. I am using Windows, based on the language shown in the `Language bar`, i.e., the input language no matter what keyboard layout you have.

Comment: Good luck with that then, Emacs surely doesn't expose such functionality (it just receives keysyms, really) and Windows probably has an API call somewhere an external program needs to use. Or an external program could detect such changes (or be invoked directly on changes) and execute code in the running Emacs instance if you were using the daemon.

Comment: Alternatively you could forego size changes for English and German and instead set up DejaVu Sans Mono to be always used for arabic glyphs, this can be set up with fontsets for glyph ranges. However, [all fontset recources I've encountered until now are targeted at Linux users](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontSets), there's only [outdated information for Windows users available](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontSetsForNTEmacs).

Comment: Changing the font based on the language is actually rare — it's more common to change the font based on the *script* (so German and English would use one font, while Arabic and Persian would use another). Emacs supports different fonts for different scripts  through [fontsets](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fontsets.html). If you change the input language, do you want to change the font for subsequently inserted text only? For the current buffer/window/frame? For all buffers/windows/frames?

Comment: @Gilles, imagine you have a buffer containing both English and Arabic text. The question is what is best way to make Emacs smart enough to recognize language based on input text and then changing the font accordingly?

Comment: @doctorate Your comment is as ambiguous as your question. Suppose you type a sentence in Arabic, then in the same buffer you type a sentence in English. Do you want to switch the font for the whole buffer, or just for the second sentence?

Comment: @Gilles, sorry for any ambiguity, just for the second sentence.

Comment: @doctorate Ok. Next question: if you yank (paste) some text which is one English sentence and one Arabic sentence, in what font should the yanked text be? The current font? The English in your English font and the Arabic in your Arabic font? And if you open a file containing mixed English and Arabic, what font(s) should the buffer use?

Comment: @Gilles, In case of yanking, it should keep the font of the *copied* text. Anything else should follow the currently active keyboard layout whatever set by the user.

Comment: @doctorate I'm talking about yanking text without any formatting, so no font indication. And what about the case of opening a text file?

Comment: @Gill to answer your last question, depends on whether your code is intended to be language-bar-aware or not. if it will somehow recognize the currently active keyboard layout in the machine, then it will follow that keyboard layout no matter what file you open.

Comment: @Gilles another approach may be, to set a default value say English and font1, but then if someone would like to write in a another language it will change to the corresponding font somehow.

Comment: I still don't understand whether you want to use the font as a visual indicator of the current keyboard setting, or if you want to use different fonts for Arabic characters and Latin characters.

Comment: Ok, please edit your question to clarify it. And [fontsets](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fontsets.html) are probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you said you wanted to depend on the Windows language bar. The Windows [Get-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852165.aspx) Cmdlet in Window PowerShell provides the necessary information.

Thus, when creating a new buffer, you need to run `PowerShell Get-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride` and parse the ouput. If you do this for *every* buffer, even for temporary buffers, my guess is that this slow you down very much. It would be better to write a function that can be added to hooks such as `find-file-hooks`. The functions on this hook are only called when you open a file for editing.

Calling a command and capturing the output happens using `(shell-command-to-string COMMAND)`. Comparing a string to some other values happens via `(string-match REGEXP STRING)`. Setting the font for a particular buffer involves calling `(face-remap-add-relative FACE &rest SPECS)`. The face you are interested in is called `default`. The specs you want are `:family` and `:height`, the font family and the font size in tenths of points.

Thus, perhaps (untested, since I'm not on Windows):

```
(defun my-buffer-setup ()
  (let ((output (shell-command-to-string "PowerShell Get-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride")))
    (cond ((string-match "arabic" output)
           (face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :height 140))
          ((string-match "english" output)
           (face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "Consolas" :height 110))
          ((string-match "german" output)
           (face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "Consolas" :height 120)))))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-buffer-setup)
```

Good luck. :)

Comment: About your choice of hook – I'll often create temporary buffers for notes.  These aren't associated with any file, so `find-file-hook` is never run.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yeah, the correct solution depends on how you want to use Emacs. You could look at `buffer-list-update-hook`.

Comment: I could not test it either bcz this powershell command was first introducted in Win8 and it seems there is no equivalent in win7. My machine has Ubuntu too, can you please extend this function to recognize system on machine and run the corresponding function based on system used? I would like to test it on Ubuntu first and meanwhile I have to look for the correct cmd command to inquire about the input lanugage in Windwos 7 32bit.

Comment: Somebody else will have to do this, as I don't have access to those systems.

Comment: @AlexSchröder, as a workaround can you please care to answer the post here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/how-to-assign-a-certain-font-for-each-text-input-method-in-emacs-24